# Deleting node in list

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, singly-linked-list, realloc

```
*x = L->list[i];      /* Save the deleted element to parameter x */
for(j = i+1; j <= L->size-1; j++)
L->list[i] = L->list[i+1];
L->size--;            /* The number of data elements is reduced by 1*/
return 1;
```

I can't delete the node fully, instead of this, its just replacing the value, but the node itself is not deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within this for loop

```
for(j = i+1; j <= L->size-1; j++)
L->list[i] = L->list[i+1];
```

the variable `i` used in this statement

```
L->list[i] = L->list[i+1];
```

is not being changed.

It seems you mean

```
for(j = i+1; j < L->size; j++)
    L->list[j-1] = L->list[j];
```

If the array `list` is allocated dynamically then you should reallocate it as for example

```
for(j = i+1; j < L->size; j++)
    L->list[j-1] = L->list[j];
L->size--;

T *tmp = realloc( L->list, L->size * sizeof( *tmp ) );
if ( tmp != NULL ) L->list = tmp;
```

You will need to substitute `T` with the actual type of elements of the array. I am using `T` because it is unknown from your question what is the type of elements of the array.